# Как добавить время добавления заметки в TODO-list React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Добавил время заметки в компонент React с помощью toLocaleTimeString(), проблема сейчас в том что время добавления заметки обновляется при каждом взаимодействии страницы, подскажите как решить эту проблему ?

Компонент с добавлением заметки, включает в себя кнопку Remove, div с заметкой, время:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../listItem/index.css';
import Button from '../button/';
const ListItem = ({ todoName, remove }) => {
    return(
        <div className="item">
            <div className="item_text">
                { todoName }
            </div>
            <div
                className="date"
            >{ new Date().toLocaleTimeString() }
            </div>
            <div>
                <button
                    onClick={() => remove(todoName)}
                    className="item_btn"
                >
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default ListItem;
```

Общий компонент приложения App:

```
import React from 'react';
import Input from './components/input/';
import Button from './components/button/';
import ListItem from './components/listItem/';
import './App.css';
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      inputValue: '',
      todoList: []
    }
  }
  onChangeInput = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: event.target.value
    })
  }
  onClickBtn = () => {
    const { inputValue, todoList } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      todoList: [inputValue, ...todoList],
      inputValue: ''
    });
  }
  onRemoveTodo = (todoName) => {
    const { todoList } = this.state;
    const todoIndex = todoList.findIndex((str) => str === todoName);
    const newTodoList = [...todoList.slice(0, todoIndex), ...todoList.slice(todoIndex + 1)];
    this.setState({
      todoList: newTodoList,
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { inputValue, todoList } = this.state;
    return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1 className="h1">TO<span className="span_h1">DO</span> list</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="control">
        <input
          className="input"
          type="search"
          value={ inputValue }
          onChange={ this.onChangeInput }
        />
        <button
          className="btn"
          onClick={ this.onClickBtn }
        >
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="table">
        {todoList.map((todoStr) => {
          return(
            <ListItem 
              key={ todoStr }
              todoName={ todoStr }
              remove={ this.onRemoveTodo }
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Так вы же не сохраняете время. Вы сохраняете текст туду, а время каждый раз рендерится новое. Вам надо в ваш `todoList` сохранять время и потом его выводить

Comment: @SwaD
Окей, я записал в константу const date = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(); дальше добавляю эту константу в div: <div className="date">{ date }</div>, но в таком случае, на новых заметках время не обновляется, остается таким же как и при последнем обновлении страницы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придется поменять структуру данных хранения туду листа.
Допустим, единица будет выглядеть так:

```
const todo = {
    toDoDate: '',
    todoStr: ''
}
```

Тогда, функция сохранения будет выглядеть так

```
onClickBtn = () => {
    const { inputValue, todoList } = this.state;
    // Сохраняем текст и дату
    const todo = {
        todoStr: inputValue,
        toDoDate: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
    }
    this.setState({
        todoList: [todo, ...todoList],
        inputValue: ''
    });
}
```

Компонент рендера ListItem. Показываем сохраненную дату

```
const ListItem = ({todoName, remove, toDoDate}) => {
    return (
        <div className="item">
            <div className="item_text">
                {todoName}
            </div>
            <div
                className="date"
            >{toDoDate} 
            </div>
            <div>
                <button
                    onClick={() => remove(todoName)}
                    className="item_btn"
                >
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

И сам рендер меняем так и передаем в компонент сохраненную дату

```
<ListItem
    key={ todoStr.todoStr }
    todoName={ todoStr.todoStr }
    remove={ this.onRemoveTodo }
    toDoDate={ todoStr.toDoDate }
/>
```

Теперь дата добавляется в момент сохранения и уже больше не меняется для записи.

- необходимо будет переписать функцию удаления(тут, я так думаю, сами справитесь).

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает